# Inconsistent latency values between Dropwizard metrics and JMeter in Netty server

Tags: java, jmeter, netty, dropwizard, metrics

I have a Netty HTTP server which I am testing by sending requests through Apache JMeter. I am using Dropwizard metrics library to measure latency on the server. I am having a problem with Dropwizard metrics showing different values than JMeter for latency (Average and 99th percentile), but only at times.

The processing happens in a seperate thread pool created using the ThreadPoolExecutor class. However I replaced the actual processing to be done in Test.java with a sleep statement so that I know how long the processing takes.

My code is as follows

LatencyTester.java

```
public class LatencyTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        displayMetrics.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Metrics(), 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        new NettyServer().run();
    }
}
```

NettyServer.java

```
public class NettyServer {

    ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public NettyServer() {
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {

        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(7,7,100, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            Timer.Context context = Metrics.TIMER.time(); //Start Dropwizard metrics timer
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
                            p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
                            p.addLast(new NettyServerHandler(executor, context));
                        }
                    }).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128).childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(15000).sync();

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

NettyServerHandler.java

```
public class NettyServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {

    private Future<ByteBuf> result;
    private Timer.Context cntx;
    private ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool;

    public NettyServerHandler(ThreadPoolExecutor pool, Timer.Context cntx) {
        this.cntx = cntx;
        this.threadPool = pool;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) throws Exception {
        Test tst = new Test();
        result = threadPool.submit(tst);
        boolean keepAlive = HttpUtil.isKeepAlive(msg);
        FullHttpResponse response = null;
        response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK, result.get());
        String contentType = msg.headers().get(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if (contentType != null) {
            response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
        }
        response.headers().setInt(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
        if (!keepAlive) {
            ctx.write(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        } else {
            response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.KEEP_ALIVE);
            ctx.write(response);
        }
        ctx.flush();
        cntx.stop();  //Stop Dropwizard metrics timer
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test implements Callable<ByteBuf> {

    public Test() {
    }

    @Override
    public ByteBuf call() throws Exception {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        return (Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Done".getBytes()));
    }
}
```

Here are some results I got after running a few tests on JMeter each with a duration of 5 minutes. Both the server and JMeter are running on my laptop. Server threads below refer to the value set for the ThreadPoolExecutor instance in NettyServer.java (Latency values below are in ms)
ServerThreads, JMeterThreads, MetricsAverage, Metrics99thP, JMeterAvg, JMeter99thP
1, 1, 5018, 5167, 5012, 5031
1, 7, 33407, 35165, 33380, 35003
5, 17, 15695, 19998, 16667,19970         - Average different by 1 second
50, 50, 8963, 15032, 15356, 29959        - Big difference
7, 23, 11295, 14965, 16121, 20002        - Big difference

Why do some of these tests show inconsistencies with JMeter and Metrics results? Am I doing something wrong in where I start and stop the Dropwizard Metrics timer?

What can I do to accurately measure the request latencies on the server side so that they will show the time taken since the requests were received until the replies are sent?

Comment: Wouldn't JMeter be measuring full roundtrip while DropWizard is measuring time once you hit your Java process?

Comment: In the Netty code, I thought I added the statements to start and stop the timer at the place the request is received and the reply is sent. Am I wrong here? Also since I am running these locally I assumed network latency wouldn't have a big effect

Comment: Unless you're running on a completely isolated test network where you're machines are the only machines turned on, I wouldn't make that assumption. As Yuri pointed out in his answer there is also potential latency on the client.

Answer (score 3):

Latency from Server's (Netty here) & Client's (JMeter respectively) standpoint are quite different things by their very design, thus they simply CAN'T be matching.

What they can be, though, is that client's latency most likely would include server's latency - thus, JMeter-side values would be always greater (there's only averages & percentiles in what you've shown - but it's true for them there).

Just look at the Latency definition for Jmeter:

> **Latency**. JMeter measures the latency ***from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received***.
>   Thus ***the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the
>   request as well as assembling the first part of the response***, which
>   in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as
>   Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over
>   the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is
>   experienced by a browser or other application client.

See?

And Server have zero knowledge of that stages happening there on the Client (and counted into latency).
Neither it knows about what's going on along the network path.

Conclusion: what you see is totally expected.

**UPD:** It was pointed out, that one of the server-side measurements exceeds JMeter one in the edge case. That's interesting & here I'm trying to explain how that is possible.

*Disclaimer first*: I'm not aware of what happens in guts of the toolkit you're using there (so don't beat me up too hard if I miss).

Although, with some help of the common sense reasoning, I can guess that:

1) The issue is that you stop your timer AFTER the flush.
Which seem to be synchronous there.

2) Thus, your latency measurement on the server side INCLUDES the full flush of the buffer.

3) While JMeter measures latency UP TO first chunk arrival & assembly.

4) In most cases, the server's fast enough to flush, faster than network + JMeter can gulp it.

5) But in some edge cases, the server or network just stumbles upon something, and last chunks are getting late.

Comment: Thanks @Yuri G. Yes I agree that they can't be matching. But I thought they would always be close with JMeter being a bit higher. But in the first 2 tests above and the 99th percentile of latency in the 3rd test, the values I got from Dropwizard metrics is slightly higher than the values JMeter has shown. How could this be? Also, is the place where I start and end the dropwizard timer correct if I want to measure the latency as much as possible on the server?

Comment: @Nilushan your 3rd results can happen if the client is experiencing low latency, network isn't saturated for most and then there may be a few outliers skewing the 99th percentile. The 99th percentile is the largest number covered by the 99% mark. So if you have 98% of requests completing in half a second, 1 that completed in 30 seconds, and 1 that completed in 50 seconds, your 99th percentile is going to be 30 seconds. Your average (mean) will be much lower (1.29s).  Factor in the network and client and you could get a higher server number. Of course, there could also be a bug in your tests.

Comment: Well, good point. Although, I think I spotted the answer in your code. Updated my answer. Hope that looks legit to you, @Nilushan.